# Trying to understand a basic homotopy between two functions.

Tags: functions, notation, homotopy-theory, transformation

Define: $\phi(x)=\exp(1/\ln(x)).$

> Q: Is the following sufficient notation to express a homotopy between $\phi$ and some arbitrary power of it, $\phi^t?$

$$\phi,\phi^t:\phi \to \phi^t$$

I want to prove that this is a homotopic map between the two functions, meaning that $\phi$ can be continuously deformed into $\phi^t, t\in\Bbb R^+.$

I'd like for $t$ to be the amount of time it takes for the mapping to occur. For example, $\phi$ continuously deformed into itself would take $t=0$ units of time. And $\phi$ mapped to $\phi^t$ would take $t$ units of time. Hopefully that makes sense.

> Q: Does a homotopic map encode anything about a "speed" at which the functions are mapped to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't talk about "speed", since of course you can define the same homotopy by making $t$ vary over an interval of any lenght, using a reparametrization. Moreover, it's very important to know which are the sets between your functions are defined since, for example, if codomain is a convex vector space (or more generally star-shaped) **every** two functions are homotopic.

Comment: Another example: when you join two homotopies you get a new homotopy; while usually they are all defined in the interval $[0,1]$, the join should "obviously" take more time, but this is not readable in the homotopy itself.